# How can I handle multithreaded UnitTests of repository to simulate concurrency?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, concurrency, nunit

I'm building mvc3 application that should serve about 1000-2000 concurrent users,
I implemented Castle Active Record and simple repository pattern, now i need to unit test all this that it won't crash on concurrency and in multi-thread environment like iis.
How should I do it?

I'm using nunit testing framework.

My Repository:

```
//interface
public interface IAbstractRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Create(T model);
    void Update(T model);
    void Delete(T model);
    int Count();

    T FindById(object id);
    T FindOne(params ICriterion[] criteria);
    IList<T> FindAll();
    IList<T> FindAllByCriteria(params ICriterion[] criteria);
}
```

//concrete implementation

```
public class AbstractRepository<T> : IAbstractRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void IAbstractRepository<T>.Create(T model)
    {
        ActiveRecordMediator<T>.Save(model);
    }

    void IAbstractRepository<T>.Update(T model)
    {
        ActiveRecordMediator<T>.Update(model);
    }

    void IAbstractRepository<T>.Delete(T model)
    {
        ActiveRecordMediator<T>.Delete(model);
    }

    int IAbstractRepository<T>.Count()
    {
        return ActiveRecordMediator<T>.Count();
    }

    T IAbstractRepository<T>.FindById(object id)
    {
        return ActiveRecordMediator<T>.FindByPrimaryKey(id);
    }

    T IAbstractRepository<T>.FindOne(params ICriterion[] criteria)
    {
        return ActiveRecordMediator<T>.FindOne(criteria);
    }

    IList<T> IAbstractRepository<T>.FindAll()
    {
        return ActiveRecordMediator<T>.FindAll();
    }

    IList<T> IAbstractRepository<T>.FindAllByCriteria(params ICriterion[] criteria)
    {
        return ActiveRecordMediator<T>.FindAll(criteria);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's no longer a unit test what you are trying to do. It's a load test. There are some tools out there that allow you to record some scenario and then simulate concurrent access to your web application executing this scenario:

- [Visual Studio Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923685.aspx)
- [loadUI](http://www.loadui.org/)
- [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Pylot](http://www.pylot.org/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/)

Comment: hypothetical question: how can i use multithread approach in here to simulate for me many users at least show me an example of code? 
Before i go to use these cool tools?
+1 for the nice answer.

Comment: There's no code. The idea is that those tools allow you to record a scenario of using your web application. Then you configure them to execute this scenario under load. They will take care of spawning threads and hamerring your web application. Obviously your application needs to be deployed first so that the tests are more realistic. You could have a specific environment to perform those kind of tests. It's not always a good idea to launch them in production.

Comment: So for example if i see an error of concurrency problem how should i approach this?

Comment: for example i want to update some user details with two threads - he came from website and in the same time i want to update his data because he came from iphone application. How should i take care of this situation? 
Please show me an example of using multithreading in asp.net-mvc3 application and code example will be excellent :)

Comment: I don't understand what threads you are talking about. ASP.NET automatically handles threads for you so that you don't need to worry. When a request arrives the runtime will take care of processing the request. I also don't understand what example of multithreading you are asking for. In ASP.NET MVC you write controller actions that process user requests. If 2 user requests come in parallel 2 different instances of this controller will be spawned to process them. If you access a database in this controller action it is up to the database to handle this situation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11005/discussion-between-iamstalker-and-darin-dimitrov)